# Fadeout effect for TimeManager (update for QGIS 3.8?)

Tags: qgis

I'm working on an animation with the TimeManager plugin, but instead of immediately disappearing or accumulating, I'm hoping to have my points fade out.

I found an article on QGIS Planet by Anita Graser that suggests using the following code to fade out the color and decrease the size of the point to nothing:

```
color_hsv(  
  311,
  scale_exp( 
    minute(age($animation_datetime,"t_datetime")),
    0,60,
    100,0,
    0.2
  ),
  90
)
```

and

```
scale_exp( 
  minute(age($animation_datetime,"t_datetime")),
  0,60,
  24,0,
  0.2
)
```

I tried copying these expressions into the expression editors next to the fill color and size options for the symbols, but I get an error that says "Expression is invalid" and it says the "$animation_datetime" function is not known.

Anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: `$animation_datetime` isn't a standard QGIS expression builder function. It must be a custom function, which either comes with the TimeManager plugin, or else you missed a step where you were supposed to create it yourself. It it's the first case, maybe the name of the function changed from when the tutorial was written (I'm guessing pre-QGIS3) until now.

Comment: I found this quote from a [2-year old post](https://anitagraser.com/2017/08/14/movement-data-in-gis-7-animated-trajectories-with-timemanager/), which makes it sound like it's a custom function: "TimeManager exposes an `animation_datetime()` function which returns the current animation timestamp" Note the different syntax, `animation_datetime()` instead of `$animation_datetime`. Based on the Expression Builder help, it looks like `animation_datetime()` is the current correct syntax.

Comment: Yes, that worked- thank you!

Comment: Could you also explain which part of this indicates the color? Currently it fades from a magenta-like color to white, but I'm looking to have it fade from red to transparent, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$animation_datetime isn't a standard QGIS expression builder function. This quote from a [2-year old post](https://anitagraser.com/2017/08/14/movement-data-in-gis-7-animated-trajectories-with-timemanager/) makes it sound like it's a custom function that comes with the TimeManager plugin:

> "TimeManager exposes an animation_datetime() function which returns the current animation timestamp" (Source: Blog post by Anita Graser, *Movement data in GIS #7: animated trajectories with TimeManager*)

Note the different syntax, `animation_datetime()` instead of `$animation_datetime`. 
Based on the Expression Builder help, it looks like `animation_datetime()` is the current correct syntax.

---

Changing the color is possible once you understand the different parts of the first expression you provided. Make use of the excellent help section built into the Expression Builder. Search for the different functions used in that expression (`color_hsv`, `scale_exp`, `minute` and `age`), and read their descriptions. The descriptions include proper syntax and examples. Use this information to adapt the expression.

For example, here's the description for the `color_hsv` function:

> ***function color_hsv*** Returns a string representation of a color based on its hue, saturation, and value attributes.
>
> *Syntax* `color_hsv(hue,saturation,value)`
>
> *Arguments*
>
> - **hue** hue of the color, as an integer value from 0 to 360
> - **saturation** saturation percentage of the color as an integer value from 0 to 100
>     value
> - **value** percentage of the color as an integer from 0 to 100
>
> *Examples* `color_hsv(40,100,100)` → 255,170,0

That's not super helpful if you don't understand HSV (Hue, Saturation and Value) notation. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) has an unnecessarily detailed explanation, but if you scroll down past the mathematical formulas you'll find [a table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Examples) with some basic colors and their corresponding HSV values. If I correctly understand (and I'm not 100% sure I do) for red you would want the values (0,100,100). Note that the table in the Wikipedia article has its S and V values represented as decimal numbers from 0.000 to 1.000, while QGIS's `color_hsv()` function wants S and V as percentages from 0 to 100.

To make it fade to transparent instead of white, use the `color_hsva()` function instead of `color_hsv()`. This function uses HSVA notation, which is just HSV with an added alpha (transparency) parameter.

> - **alpha** alpha component as an integer value from 0 (completely transparent) to 255 (opaque)

If HSV notation bums you out, take a look at the other functions in the Color section. There are color functions that accept input in other notations, including CMYK, HSL, HSV, and RGB. All of these functions have a version that accepts an alpha (transparency) component.